# Simple Odata Client - How to add oAuth Token in each request header?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, access-token, auth-token, simple.odata.client

In Microsoft oData v4 proxy client, there is an option to add auth token into each request. It can be achieved by following way:

```
var container = new Default.Container(new Uri(http://localhost:9000/));

//Registering the handle to the BuildingRequest event. 
container.BuildingRequest += (sender, e) => OnBuildingRequest(sender, e, accessToken);


//Every time a OData request is build it adds an Authorization Header with the acesstoken 
private static void OnBuildingRequest(object sender, BuildingRequestEventArgs e, TokenResponse token)
{
 e.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.AccessToken);
}
```

How can I do the same using simple odata client?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently I should provide an explanation of why this is the answer.

Explanation: this is how you add the token for Simple ODataClient.

```
var settings = new ODataClientSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9000/"));
settings.BeforeRequest += delegate(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    message.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.AccessToken);
};

var client = new ODataClient(settings);
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of ***why*** this is the answer.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using the delegate method to intercept and add the Authorization header on every Http call, a clearer/cleaner solution is to instantiate the ODataClient with an HttpClient instance.

This also allows you to control the HttpClient lifecycle and re-use it ( as you should be doing normally anyway! ) otherwise ODataClient will create a new HttpClient instance on every call and that is just inefficient and causes lots of churn on the socket layer. Not normally a problem but can be on high volume code so just a good habit.

The code below is an extract of a .Net core app using an Azure AD OAuth2 token to connect to a Dynamics 365 OData Web API.

```
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(yourODataServiceRootURL);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", yourBearerAccessToken);

        //Use the httpClient we setup with the Bearer token header
        var odataSettings = new ODataClientSettings(httpClient, new Uri("api/data/v9.1", UriKind.Relative));

        var odataClient = new ODataClient(odataSettings);
```