# How to add Bearer token to Simple OData Client

Tags: xamarin.forms, odata, simple.odata.client

New to OData, I need to access SAP Odata Web Service that required Authentication and Token.  Say I have the token hardcoded. How to add this token to Simple OData Client?

```
var settings = new Simple.OData.Client.ODataClientSettings();

settings.BaseUri = new Uri("https://..../UoM?$filter=wer eg '1000' &format=json");

settings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user1", "usrpwd");
var client = new ODataClient(settings);
```

Please kindly help me.

Update --

In this link : [Simple Odata Client - How to add oAuth Token in each request header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867218/simple-odata-client-how-to-add-oauth-token-in-each-request-header)

It didnot show how to add the hardcoded Token. For my problem, I need to add a given token and make a Odata Request. I check the Odata.org website, I dont seems to find any example for my case.

I have no experience on simple.Odata.client, Can some1 be kind enough to show me how.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Odata Client - How to add oAuth Token in each request header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867218/simple-odata-client-how-to-add-oauth-token-in-each-request-header)

Comment: Can you provide a link reference for Token and Authorization for Simple.OData.Client  I need your help.

Comment: What do you mean with a 'hardcoded token'? The linked answer shows how you can alter outgoing request headers so you can pass authentication info, why can't that work for you?

Comment: What is Default.Container?? I don't have it in Simple.OData.Client. How to add token manually, say , token ="xddwewe ==" ?

Comment: Hey @MilkBottle, is my answer of any use to you?

Comment: The URL you are using is incorrect, reference my answer below. You are not clear on exactly what type of authorization you need to do or what the token you have to use is however my answer should also address that.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use the `ODataClientSettings.BeforeRequest` action to alter the request before it is sent.

In the example below I set the `Authorization` header of the request to '`Bearer <Token>`':

```
settings.BeforeRequest = req => {
    req.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your_Token_Here");
};
```

Of course it is up to you to configure the request for you specific type of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you use in your example is clearly wrong and not the OData URL for SAP.

You need the base URL for the "yourODataServiceRootURL" below and then add the relative path later in the ODataclient setting eg. "api/data/v9.1"

Instead of using the delegate method to intercept and add the Authorization header on every Http call, a clearer/cleaner solution is to instantiate the ODataClient with an HttpClient instance.

This also allows you to control the HttpClient lifecycle externally.

The code below is an extract of a .Net core app using an Azure AD OAuth2 token to connect to a Dynamics 365 OData Web API.

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(yourODataServiceRootURL);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", yourBearerAccessToken);

//Use the httpClient we setup with the Bearer token header
var odataSettings = new ODataClientSettings(httpClient, new Uri("api/data/v9.1", UriKind.Relative));

var odataClient = new ODataClient(odataSettings);
```